# Why is System76 not mentioned on the Ubuntu certified hardware partners page?

Tags: hardware, laptop

Why is [System76](https://www.system76.com) not mentioned on [the Ubuntu certified hardware partners website](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/)

They are producing **only** Ubuntu preinstalled and optimized computers:
https://www.system76.com/laptops/model/galu1

They even have an Ubuntu-logo key instead of win key between ctrl and alt ;)

Why are they not mentioned there?

Comment: Have you tried contacting system76 and asking them yourself?  I am still leaning towards "too localized" or "off-topic".

Comment: Maybe because they aren't the manufacturer? From what I understand they assemble and make the software/BIOS/drivers for the systems

Comment: This is a question about Canonical and not the Ubuntu OS.

Answer (score 8):

We don't submit our Computers to Canonical for Validation testing for a number of reasons.

- We have a very rapid hardware development cycle, and submitting to Canonical for validation would slow that testing and development down and reduce our ability to launch new product quickly.
- We do a large suite of in-house testing to ensure that Ubuntu runs flawlessly out of the box on all of our computers. This that instead of needing a validation to tell you it works, simply buying System76 from the start guarantees compatibility with Ubuntu, since that's all we work with.

Comment: It would still be good promotion for you, maybe. Perhaps you could have some of your already released models validated and linked to from ubuntu.com to see how it affects your page hits... Also, I think it would help the Ubuntu community as a whole to get more people using Ubuntu on the hardware that was best tailored for it.

Answer (score 5):

From the Ubuntu website:

> OEMs submit systems to Canonical's testing facility where certification testing and validation is performed by Canonical engineers.

It is possible that System76 did not submit their systems for certification. If they did, it is possible that their systems were not up to [Canonical's standards](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/test-suite/). One can only speculate as to why System76's systems are not Ubuntu-certified. For a more definite answer, you should contact System76.

A machine does not need to be certified for Ubuntu to work on it. From the Ubuntu website:

> Ubuntu works on a range of hardware which has not been certified by the manufacturer. The Ubuntu community works together to test and report the range of systems that work with Ubuntu. You can see a list of tested systems with their results in the Ubuntu Friendly site.